# Can I create my own custom 'language' for OneNote spellchecking?

Tags: spell-check, microsoft-onenote

Do you know a way to add SQL, Perl, C# or any other programming language's **keywords** as a **custom language** to OneNote?

We use OneNote to document our work.

When I add code (SQL, other) to a new page, the code goes red, since the spelling is not correct German (surprise). I'd like to be able to assign a language..

Answer (score 1):

Having worked with it a lot, I can personally vouch that there is nothing in the underlying OneNote document model or APIs that allows for control over what is spell-checked or not. If there were, it would be possible to write an add-in to mark blocks of text as code (which is something I have been wanting to do for a long time), but so far it is not possible given the many limitations of the OneNote API.

Others seem to concur: [How can spell checking be turned off for a portion of a OneNote page](https://superuser.com/questions/342964/how-can-spell-checking-be-turned-off-for-a-portion-of-a-onenote-page) .