# Possible to disable spell checking in OneNote for a specific page only?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

In OneNote, I'd like to disable spell checking for a single page which is written in a fictional language and thus full of squiggly lines. I'd like to keep spell checking on for all other notebooks / pages.

Is that possible in OneNote 2013?

Answer (score 75):

To disable the spell check on a single page or for a section of text on a page, select all the text and change the dictionary to a language for which you do not have a dictionary (like Frisian or Somali) (now in 2021 Frisian isn't available and it is a little different in how you do it).  The squiggly lines all disappear.

This is the process:

1. Select all the text on the page
2. Choose Review > Language > Set Proofing Language
3. Choose the language
4. Close the Proofing Language Sidebar

Process 2:

1. select the text with the lines under it.
2. click the "change language" option.
3. search for Somali
4. click it

Comment: Ths works the best for a page by page setting. but some languages mess with your style settings.  I found 'Alsatian' to work well (and its near the top)

Comment: This is how different bugs turn into features. Thanks a lot for the quick and easy solution!

Comment: Is the Review option removed ? I can't find it in the desktop app

Comment: This works, but is of course a fairly terrible hack; ensure you pick a language for which WIndows doesn't think you need diacritics and which has no special formatting (like Hebrew). As an actual Frisian, I object to your example ;-)

Comment: @YetAnotherBot As of today (on macOS), see `Tools > Set Proofing Language...`

Comment: this is beautiful! never would've guessed language settings would banish the squigglies!

Answer (score 19):

Note that for more recent editions of OneNote (I'm using 2016) you can turn off the spell check markings all together through File->Options->Proofing -> Hide Spelling and grammar errors. This doesn't quite satisfy the question since it is being asked how to turn it off on a single page, but it may be of use to someone.

Answer (score 15):

I opened the spelling pane (REVIEW > Spelling) and clicked ignore over and over until the page had no red squiggles.

That quick and dirty solution was a little tedious, but it worked for my small page full of red squiggles. Opening the spelling pane and click-click-clicking only took a few seconds to ignore fifty misspellings.

The Ignore option only ignores for the particular instance of that misspelling. Another instance of the same misspelling (even on the same page) will still be marked with the red squiggle.

Comment: Click the ignore button once, then hold down the 'i' key on your keyboard until it ignores them all.

Comment: This post and the comment by @bradvido provide the best solution

Comment: I agree that *this* should be the accepted answer. So much easier to open the review pane and hold "i".  Bravo!!

Comment: Important to note that holding down the 'i' key (for ignore) can ONLY be done by going into the Review Spelling interface.  This differs from pressing 'g' on any page in normal view. I hadn't caught that the first time I read the comment by @bradvido.  Ignoring words by holding the 'i' key down fixes errors at the speed of your keyboard buffer!  Doing this is absolutely the best solution, because clicking the button with the mouse is slow and laborious (aka repetitive strain injury).  It is relatively quick, allows you to ignore everything without changing languages for a page.  Bravo Bravido!

Comment: As a programmer, this is a life-saver.  I store a lot of code snippets as I work through problems and projects.  Because OneNote's languages doesn't take into account code syntax, let alone variable or method names, I have right-clicked and ignored text tens of thousands of time.  This will be a real time saver!

Answer (score 13):

Yes, if you install and use the free [Onetastic add-in](https://getonetastic.com/) and the ["No Spell Check" macro](https://getonetastic.com/macroland&id=1DF08B3C629840759A86237CC090F8A9).

[image]

This answer was [originally provided by another user](https://superuser.com/a/893515/466273) in a related Q&A.

Comment: If an answer on another question also answers this one, there's a good chance the questions are duplicates.  If so, it's a better practice to flag the question as a potential duplicate rather than replicate the answer.  If the questions aren't duplicates, you can link to the other answer in a comment with a little more rep.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @fixer1234. The other question is different enough, thus not a duplicate. Can you advise me how I should best provide "a little more rep?" I thought it was okay as-is.

Comment: The rep reference wasn't about the quality of the answer, it referred to having enough reputation for comment privileges, at which point you could just provide a link to the other answer in a comment.   :-)

Comment: There should be a link already to the other answer in my last sentence. What am I missing or misunderstanding? :-)

Comment: Your link within the answer is correct attribution since as an answer, it closely duplicates the other answer.  Once you have enough rep to comment, it would be better to not replicate the answer at all.  Rather, post a comment on the question with a link to the other answer.  That avoids duplication.  Some people might also see this answer as siphoning rep from the author of the other answer since it's essentially the same.  A comment with a link would direct people to the original answer, where any upvoting would accrue to that author.  Technically, what you posted is OK, though.

Comment: @fixer1234 The problem with this approach is that a comment is harder to spot for someone who will be looking for an answer in answer section. If there are multiple answers, I can easily miss a comment, since I am looking into the answers (since comments do not concern me directly). The fact that EJ Mak found the relevant question and realized the answer is appropriate in a dfiferent question context serves as a good enough reason for him to deserve my upvote. Since he provided the link for the origin, I can go and upvote the other answer too, if I want.

Comment: @Ev0oD, good point.  If there weren't any answers yet, a comment would stand out, especially if there isn't a long comment thread.  If there are already a bunch of answers, a comment might be less obvious, especially if there are a lot of them.  If it is actually a duplicate, a formal link is created, and it becomes pretty hard to miss.

Answer (score -2):

## **solution:**

Go to Tools Menu > Spelling Tab > Spelling Option

You will find all the option ticked or unticked.

Then Untick all the options .

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. He only wants no spell checking for a **single** page**